# Formal definition of a Regression Tree

Tags: regression, cart, definition

I am looking for a formal mathematical definition of a Regression Tree. My current idea would look like this:

*"A Regression Tree is a function $T(X\in\mathbb{R}^n)$ that splits the feature space $\mathbb{R}^n$ into $K\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ mutually exclusive and exhaustive subsets $S_k,\quad S_i\cap S_j=\emptyset,\quad\cup_{k=1}^KS_k=\mathbb{R}^n$ and outputs a value $A_k \in \mathbb{R}$ according to the subset $S_k$ the input vector $X$ falls into ($X\in S_k$)"*

So, my questions are:

1. Does this definition make sense or are there any flaws to it?
2. Is there already a similar (or better) formal definition for Regression Trees that highlight the mathematical aspect of it like my attempt tries to?

Comment: Note: arbitrary sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ may look very very ugly. What regression trees usually do is to make decisions like 'x > threshold' vs 'x <= threshold' so I would say that it needs to split the whole space into mutually exclusive and exhaustive 'cubes' and by cubes I mean sets like $\{x_1,...,x_d : a_i [</\leq] x_i [</\leq] b_i\}$ where $a_i, b_i$ might be $\pm \infty$

Comment: Also note that formally you are right, the evaluation of a tree does precisely this but just focussing on this would make the tree look 'flat', i.e. as if there is only one decision, namely $x \in S_i \Rightarrow $ prediction = value on $S_i$. However, the art of building the tree is not like that. Depending on the viewpoint it might be better to define it as a tree with decisions $x_i \leq \text{threshold}$ vs. $x_i > \text{threshold}$ attached to each node...

Comment: Moreover, the splits are sequential, where subsets are further splited in subsequent iterations. Also "value according to subset" does not sound nice. The value is some statistic of the subset - the mean (always?).

Comment: I think the basic insight here is that there are two different things: actual algebraic regression trees (nodes, leafs, connections, decisions) and their 'evaluations', i.e. the prediction function that they represent. Every tree can be turned into a predictive function but this transformation is not 'injective', i.e. there may be multiple trees looking completely different that produce the same prediction function.

Comment: @FabianWerner Adding the cube property makes total sense, thanks for that input. About the decision property, I am aware that technicaly we have a sequence of decisions just as you mentioned. However, I want to express the Regression Tree function completely as a sum of set functions that take on either the leaf value if $X\in S_k$ and $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Call $A=(A_i)_i$ the set of hyperplanes (parallel to the axis) that can be candidate as splits for your data.

Then, one can define the set of indicators overs $A_i$ (call it $S_A^1$) and their complement as a family of (independant) vectors generating a functional space (the space of the decision trees of depth 1).

Basically : $F_1=\{{\sum_iy_i1_{A_i}+y_i'1_{A_i^c}|y_i,y_i'\in\mathbb{R}}\}$.

Then, one can build : $S_A^2=\sum_{A_i}1_{A_i}S^1_{A\backslash A_i}+1_{A_i^c}S^1_{A\backslash A_i}$ (though the sum notation is a little bit abusive). This family is, in turn, the basis generating the space of functions representing the trees of depth 2.

This step can be iterated to represent trees of any depth.